# How is the market cap calculated of tokens traded on DEX like Pancakeswap?

Tags: pancakeswap

Let's start with two an example contract [0xD52B599F88A0dD095DD07dd7d98ea965192C3F2a](https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0xD52B599F88A0dD095DD07dd7d98ea965192C3F2a).

If you look at [Poocoin](https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xd52b599f88a0dd095dd07dd7d98ea965192c3f2a) or [Bogged](https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0xD52B599F88A0dD095DD07dd7d98ea965192C3F2a), both of them show market cap as:

$7,415,949,681,815,443,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Safe to say that this cannot be true.

What's the formula behind it and how can it be done better?

Answer (score 1):

ERC20 compliant tokens have a function that return the total supply:

```
 function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256)
```

The returned value is just informative. The total circulating or minted can be different.

Comment: If I used `burn` function, would that decrease `totalSupply`?